# Dynamic image source binding with fullpath in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

this problem is treated in a lot of place, but I could not find a solution that fit my need.

```
  <div class="side_bar_button">
      <img :src="require('@/assets/' + imgSrc)" > <!-- FIXME: I want to pass full path, not a part -->
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {  Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

export default Vue.extend({
    props: ["imgSrc"],
})
</script>
```

No problem, image is correctly loaded from asset with imgSrc = "logo.png".

My need :

```
<template>
  <div class="side_bar_button">
      <img :src="require(imgSrc)" > <!-- FIXME: I want to pass full path, not a part -->
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {  Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

export default Vue.extend({
    props: ["imgSrc"],
})
</script>
```

with imgSrc = "@/assets/logo.png", doesn't work. (Known problem relevant to vue-cli building).

But I don't want to limit my component prop to image source from @/assets.

Have you a way to make it works ? I'm pretty sure I can do something at webpack level to tell the build that maybe, I'll use file with path in @/asset, without typing it in the component.

Thank you

EDIT: calling component:
working case, where I use "@/assets/" + imgSrc

```
<template>
  <div class="left_nav_bar">
      <div class="column">
          <SideBarButton imgSrc="icon/icon_patient_plus.svg" />
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import SideBarButton from '@/components/SideBarButton.vue'

export default Vue.extend({
    components: {
        SideBarButton
    }
})
</script>
```

failurecase, where I use imgSrc

```
<template>
  <div class="left_nav_bar">
      <div class="column">
          <SideBarButton imgSrc="@/assets/icon/icon_patient_plus.svg" />
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import SideBarButton from '@/components/SideBarButton.vue'

export default Vue.extend({
    components: {
        SideBarButton
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: You'd have to pass the file path along with the image source through props. Could you post the file where you pass the props?

Comment: the path is well pass (vue-dev show it, and I can see it in html with {{imgSrc}}. It could be a props or even a data, the problem is the same.

Comment: If you post the parent component I can help you, without it all I can say is include the folder path along with your image source

Comment: You don't understand the problem here. Actually, if you don't precise in a static way "@/assets", the builder doesn't prepare files in assets folder. So full path '@/assets/logo.png" cannot be set dynamically.

Comment: Vue CLI cannot resolve the literal URL `@/assets/icon/icon_patient_plus.svg` when you're passing it directly as an attribute, and that is where your problem is. You will always need to rely on an `import` statement, because that is how webpack can resolve the module correctly with the appropriate loader. Is there a reason why you cannot use import statements?

Comment: less code is best. but when vue CLI see "@/Assets", it does something (like preparing file for static hosting, etc...). Can't I compensate this with some build directive ? (in the end I always finished by don't use assets at all, but only static folder ...)